Gauss Rodrigues map image
I'm trying to solve an old exam on differential geometry to prepare for my exam and I have doubts about the following point:
Having chosen an orientation, describe the image of the Gauss Rodrigues map and establish whether it is surjective.
The regular surface I'm considering is
$\varphi:A\to \mathbb{R}^3, \quad \varphi(u,v)=(u^2,uv^2,v)$
where $A=\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{(u,0)\in \mathbb{R}^2, \quad u\leq 0\}$.
In the previous point, I've found that the normal vector in $(u,v)$ is
$N(u,v)=(v^2,-2u,4u^2v)$ (if my calculations are correct)
How could I proceed? Thank you.

In the coordinates $u,v$ you have a map from a point on the surface to the normal. That is the  Gauss map. To follow the definition you should divide $N$ by its length.

Yes, I know that. However, what I have to do to describe the image of GR map?

Why is the surface in fact regular? What direction(s) is (are) missing because your domain omits the nonpositive $u$-axis? What directions are missing because of the signs of the coordinates of your non-unit $N$?
